# Writeln followed by _WriteWChar prints a question mark

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, delphi-xe6

In our legacy application we have lots of code similar to this:

```
Writeln('Line 1');
Write('Line 2:', '_': 5);
```

Under D2007 this outputs

```
Line 1
Line 2:    _
```

as expected. Under XE6 I get

```
Line 1
Line 2:?    _
```

, please note the extraneous question mark in line 2. It ist explicitly added by _WriteWChar because `t.UTF16Buffer[0]` isn't empty. This in turn is because Writeln writes to `t.MBCSBuffer[0]` (which overlaps `t.UTF16Buffer[0]`) but doesn't clear it afterwards.

My test program:

```
program WriteSpaceTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

begin
  Writeln('Line 1');
  //TTextRec(Output).UTF16Buffer[0] := #0;
  Write('Line 2:', '_': 5);
  Readln;
end.
```

The commented line is one workaround for XE6. I can also avoid using `_WriteWChar` by writing something like

```
  Write('Line 2:', '    _');
```

What I want to know: Is this a bug in XE6? If so, is it fixed in later versions? Any idea if my clear-UTF16Buffer-workaround screws something?

Comment: I think @DavidHeffernan filed a QC about this. [Write, when passed UTF-16 arguments, produces incorrect output following a call to Writeln](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=123157)

Comment: Unfortunately QC triage failed badly at that report.

Comment: Thanks to you both!

Comment: @David Yeah, I see. :-/